Can't set ID for generated-index pages on docusaurus
I am trying to set a ID for docusaurus category pages like:
docs: [
    'overall_intro',
    {
      type: 'category',
      label: 'Beginner Guide',
      link: {
        type: "generated-index",
        title: "Beginner Guide",
        id: "beginner-guide",
        description: "lorem",
      },
      items: [

but i got an error:
[1] "link.id" is not allowed
    at exports.process...

I understand the error, but when i search docusaurus documentation, i see that they set ID. So i couldn't solve the problem exaclty.
Is there any one which faced that issue or who can help me?
